# Ito's Isometry using Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $B_t$ be standard Brownian Motion.  Could someone please help me to show that $$E[(\int_{0}^{t}B_sdB_s)^2] = \int_{0}^{t}E[B_s^2]ds$$

I am sure that it has something to do with Ito's formula but I am pretty new to this stuff so some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The accepted solution computes each side, using various tricks, and sees they are equal. The exercise actually asks you to apply a very general formula, probably in your notes, which provides the result right away. This is one "advantage" of accepting answers on the spot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RHS is direct to evaluate.  The variance of $B_s$ is $s$ so:
$$\int_0^t E[B_s^2] ds = \int_0^t s ds = \frac{t^2}{2}$$

You are right about use Ito's Lemma for the LHS.
By Ito:
$$B_t^2 = t + 2\int_0^t B_s dB_s$$
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
E[(\int_0^t B_s dB_s)^2] &=& E\left[\left(\frac{B_t^2 - t}{2}\right)^2 \right] \\
    &=& \frac{1}{4}(E[B_t^4] - 2tE[B_t^2] + t^2)\\
    &=& \frac{1}{4}(3t^2 - 2t\cdot t + t^2)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks for the clear answer.  I was evaluating the LHS and trying to arrive at the RHS and I think that is why I was getting confused

Comment: Indeed, "evaluating the LHS and trying to arrive at the RHS" is what you are supposed to do, using a result in your notes.